# Hibernate: Unable to build entity manager factory (entity-mappings.xml)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate JPA on a desktop application because generic SQL queries is almost impossible and I don't want to implement my own JPA.

I want to use non annotated entity classes because I'm using a library shared by the desktop app and an android app so I want to keep everything in XML. However Hibernate failed to build entity manager factory giving me the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : com/model/entity/TransferType.xml : origin(com/model/entity/TransferType.xml)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
```

Here is the mapping file xml I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        version="2.0">

    <entity class="app.model.DeviceType">
        <table name="DEVICE_TYPE"
               schema="my_schema"
               catalog=""/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="type">
                <column name="type"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

How do I fixe this? What I am doing wrong in here?