# Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : com/orm/Sample-orm.xml : origin(com/orm/Sample-orm.xml)

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping, jboss7.x

I have faced the below issue when loading the orm file in Jboss EAP 7.0 but It was working in Weblogic.

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to resolve explicitly named mapping-file : com/orm/Sample-orm.xml : origin(com/orm/Sample-orm.xml)"}}

The same question raised in Stackoverflow but i couldn't find any solution.Please refer below URL

[Hibernate: Unable to build entity manager factory (entity-mappings.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478844/hibernate-unable-to-build-entity-manager-factory-entity-mappings-xml)

I tired to move the orm file to META-INF and tried some of the orm file has been loaded successfully but not all.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The standard location for any _orm.xml_ file is under META-INF and named as _orm.xml_. All compliant JPA providers should be able to load it from that location.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ok ... I know we can load it from com.xx.yy.module ... it will not loaded ...please let me know , how to load orm from my custom module

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm replying very late.
But since this question showed up in Google for my query, I though of answering for future users.

As shown in this [Hibernate User guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-compliant-persistence-xml-external-mappings-example), we can provide **absolute** path like this.

For Linux:

```
<mapping-file>file:///etc/opt/app/mappings/orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

For Windows:

```
<mapping-file>file:///C:\path\to\your\file\orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

I'm not sure how to provide relative path.

I hope someone gets help from this.